# Measure theoretic entropy

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, complex-dynamics

I don't know if this is an elementary question or not. In what follows all maps are continuous

Suppose that $P:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a complex polynomial of degree $d>1$ and let $\mu$ be its invariant ergodic measure of maximal entropy. Now  let $\Phi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow S$ be a surjective map (also injective outside some real algebraic set) where $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and take $Q:S\rightarrow S$. Let $\nu=\Phi_*(\mu)$ and let $\Psi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be injective such that $\Phi\circ\Psi=Id_S$.

Suppose we have following relations
$$\Phi\circ P=Q\circ\Phi,$$
and 
$$\Psi\circ Q=P\circ\Psi.$$

**So my qestion is: Does it hold $h_{\mu}(P)=h_{\nu}(Q)$?**

It is basic fact that $h_{\mu}(P)\geq h_{\nu}(Q)$, so proving other way around is trickier.

Comment: for $z \mapsto z^2$, the support of the measure of maximal entropy is the circle, which is real algebraic. If you "crush" it by the map $\Phi$, you will get strictly lower entropy. same for $z^2-2$ where the support of the measure of maximal entropy is $[-2,2]$. of course these examples are exceptional and you may wish to exclude them